# MIT jos lab,how can I set breakpoint at bootmain()

Tags: debugging, operating-system, gdb, breakpoints

**Firstly,**
I am now learning OS implementation from [MIT-jos](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2011/labs/lab1/)

and I want to trace **bootmain(void)** which locates in boot/main.c

But I don't know how to set breakpoint there,

I do set gdb source directory to both boot and obj/boot

```
(gdb) dir boot:obj/boot
Source directories searched:     
/home/osdi/lab/boot:/home/osdi/lab/obj/boot:$cdir:$cwd
```

when I set breakpoint at bootmain(void),
gdb complains:

```
(gdb) b bootmain
Function "bootmain" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

**So,how can I correctly set breakpoint at bootmain(void?)**

**Secondly,**
I can only set breakpoint by address

```
(gdb) b *0x7c00
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7c00
```

but when I want to list the code,gdb again complains "No such file or directory"

```
[   0:7c00] => 0x7c00:  cli    
Breakpoint 1, 0x00007c00 in ?? ()
(gdb) list
1   {standard input}: No such file or directory.
    in {standard input}
```

**So,how can I list the information correctly?**

thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracing in `boot/boot.asm`

```
call bootmain
    7c45: e8 c0 00 00 00 call 7d0a <bootmain>
```

`Bootmain` function starts at **0x7d0a**

Answer (score 0):

Run into same issue recently and google a while but no luck with a solution. Read gdb output and lab guide and find the root cause.

It turns out you need set symbol-file to ***boot***, then all work good. Please see following gdb output. In line '*+ symbol-file obj/kern/kernel*', we can see it use ***kernel*** as symbol-file by default. since bootmain() is located in ***boot***, so we need switch to ***boot*** symbol-file.

I've summarize it in this [blog](https://blog.csdn.net/hfyinsdu/article/details/104059465).

```
The target architecture is assumed to be i8086
[f000:fff0]    0xffff0: ljmp   $0xf000,$0xe05b
0x0000fff0 in ?? ()
+ symbol-file obj/kern/kernel

(gdb) symbol-file obj/boot/boot.out
Load new symbol table from "obj/boot/boot.out"? (y or n) y
Reading symbols from obj/boot/boot.out...done.
(gdb) b bootmain
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7d15: file boot/main.c, line 40.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
```